# "Class is not licensed for use" error

Tags: c#, winforms

In a Win32 C# App, when I run my application and hit some button I get this error ""Class is not licensed for use" and jumps to this code in my VS....

```
    if (oUCMRWPTemplate.ResultLayoutExistsInd)
    {
        try
        {
            if (oTextSvc_UnmarshallText == null)
            {
                oTextSvc_UnmarshallText = new SelectTemplate.TextSvc();
            }

            int replyHandle = lReply.Handle.ToInt32();

            sText = new StringBuilder(oTextSvc_UnmarshallText.BuildTextFromSRV(ref replyHandle, moUCMRWPTemplateLoadQual.PageWidth));
        }
        catch { }
    }
```

Debugger stops at the line that says sText = new StringBuilder....

I was wondering from this point what should I look at to find what is the issue?

Comment: Are you using and third party controls?

Comment: This one definitely seems like a third party licensing issue with a control you are using.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I suspect the problem is your `moUCMRWPTemplateLoadQual` instance.  This is likely a third party control which is not properly licensed.

The reason the debugger stops on that line is that is where you retrieve a property (`PageWidth`) which is obviously checking licensing.

Comment: thanks, the code "oTextSvc_UnmarshallText.BuildTextFromSRV" looks like it is a Interop.SelectTemplate DLL,  it is in my refrences so maybe it is not Registered? How can I register it?

Comment: I suggest you contact the author of the control, use the installer for the control, or do a quick google search on the subject.